# What should the path of healthcheck be in the target group created for Fargate Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-fargate

I deployed docker image using AWS Fargate. When I created a service out of the task definition, logs show that tomcat has no errors and app is up and running but new instances are getting constantly getting spun as health check is failing

Health Checks (On target group tied to the service)
Protocol: HTTP
Path: /Sampler/data/ping
Port: traffic/port

What is the right path for health check? 
I tried giving servicename too, but it did not work
for example: /servicename/data/ping
Can you please suggest what I am missing?

I have deployed the same war file in local by running docker run -p 8080:8080 sampler:latest (same image pushed from local to ECR) and when I hit the URL http://localhost:8080/Sampler/data/ping, I get 200 status code

Dockerfile
FROM tomcat:9.0-jre8-alpine
COPY target/Sampler-*.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps/Sampler.war
EXPOSE 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path for the health check depends on your application. Based on the information you have provided, I suspect the issue could be related to `healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds`

> **healthCheckGracePeriodSeconds**
>
> The period of time, in seconds, that the Amazon ECS service scheduler ignores unhealthy 
>     Elastic Load Balancing target health checks after a task has first started.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_Service.html

When ECS tasks took a long time to start, Elastic Load Balancing (ELB) health checks could mark the task as unhealthy and the service scheduler would shut the task down.

You can specify a health check grace period in ECS service definition parameter. This instructs the service scheduler to ignore ELB health checks for a pre-defined time period after a task has been instantiated.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-ecs-adds-elb-health-check-grace-period/